# Database Insert Query function for every amount of columns and every amount of Values and any Table

Tags: php, pdo

I try to make a Code in PHP to feed a Database with any number of Database columns and content. For that I simply supply the needed Databasecolumns in a String ($columnNames) and the Array with the Values. It is multidimensional, because in the insert sql query after a dataset the Bracket get closed and then a new Dataset begans also in Brackets. With a multidimensional Array i can add this brackets after every datasets and remove unneeded commas.
The string which I output with var_dump looks so far good. Why he don't interpret the string as he should? I also just type in the text of the placeholder and can also supply hard coded Values. Why i can't make that all with a string. Is it just because it is a string? I hardly see another way as to use a string. Because an array need to get accessed manuelly. I can't make a foreach Loop in the middle of a execute Function...  How i could give him the needed data else?

My PHP Version: 8.2.4

Anyway. I get this error and any try to fix it failed so far:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\pages\processing\database-dump-process.php:179 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\pages\processing\database-dump-process.php(179): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\pages\processing\database-dump-process.php(143): Database_dump('', 'denomination_id...', Array, Object(PDO)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\main.php(111): include_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\united-for-eternity\pages\processing\database-dump-process.php on line 179
```

I have counted it. It has the right Number of Bounds. Don't know why it not work.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle($characters), 0, $length);
 
    return $randomString;
 }

$columnNames ='colummn1, column2, column3';

//The Value Array which I want to insert in database
$columnValuesArr = [
    1 => [
        1,
        'testValue',
        1
    ],
    2 => [
        2,
        'myValue',
        1
    ],

];
$tableName = '';

insertData($tableName, $columnNames, $columnValuesArr, $conn);

function insertData ($tableName, $columnNames,$columnValuesArr, $conn) {
    $i = 0;
    $columnValues = '('; 
    $columnValuesExecute = '(';
    $columnNamesArr = explode(',', $columnNames);
    end($columnValuesArr);
    //fetch key of the last element of the array.
    $lastElementKey = key($columnValuesArr);
    foreach ($columnValuesArr as $columnKey => $columnValueDatasets) {
        foreach ($columnValueDatasets as  &$columnValue) {
            $placeholder = ':' . $columnNamesArr[$i] . generateRandomString(10);
            $placeholder = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $placeholder);
            $columnValues .= $placeholder .  ',';
            if (is_numeric($columnValue)) {
                $columnValuesExecute .= "'" . $placeholder . "'" . " => " . $columnValue . ",";
            } else {
                $columnValuesExecute .= "'" . $placeholder . "'" . " => " . "'" . $columnValue . 
                "',";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $columnValues = rtrim($columnValues, ',');
        if ($columnKey == $lastElementKey) {
            $columnValues .= ')';
        } else {
            $columnValues .= '),(';
        }
        $i = 0;
    } 
    //rtrim deleted to much. So i tried another way for deleting unwanted commas and brackets
    $columnValuesExecute = preg_replace('/\,$/','',$columnValuesExecute); 
    $columnValuesExecute = preg_replace('/^\(/','',$columnValuesExecute); 
    var_dump($columnValues, $columnValuesExecute); 
    $result = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . $columnNames . ') 
    VALUES ' . $columnValues); 
    $result->execute([$columnValuesExecute]);   
}
```

So i adjusted this  now and show my new code. I also made a function to test the query to avoid that crab comes into database.

```
insertData($tableName, $columnNames, $columnValuesArr, $conn);
//testQuery($tableName, $columnNames,$columnValuesArr);

function insertData($tableName, $columnNames,$columnValuesArr, $conn) {
    $i = 0;
    $placeholders = '';
    $columnValuePrepare = '('; 
    $columnValues = $columnValuesArr;
    $columnNamesArr = explode(',', $columnNames);
    $columnCount = count($columnNamesArr);
    end($columnValuesArr);
    //fetch key of the last element of the array.
    $lastElementKey = key($columnValuesArr);
    foreach ($columnValuesArr as $columnKey => $columnValueDatasets) {
        foreach ($columnValueDatasets as  &$columnValue) {
            $placeholders .= '?,';
            //columnValuesForTest .= $columnValue . ',' ;
            //$i++;
        }
        $placeholders = rtrim($placeholders, ',');
        $columnValuePrepare = rtrim($columnValuePrepare, ',');
        //columnValuesForTest .= rtrim($columnValuesForTest) ;
        if ($columnKey == $lastElementKey) {
            $columnValuePrepare .= $placeholders . ')';
            //columnValueForTest .= $columnValue ;
        } else {
            $columnValuePrepare .= $placeholders . '),(';
            //columnValueForTest .= $columnValue . '),(';
        }
        //$i = 0;
        $placeholders = '';
    } 
    // var_dump ('INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . $columnNames . ') 
    // VALUES ' . $columnValuePrepare);

    $i = 1;
    $databaseFetch = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . $columnNames . ') 
    VALUES ' . $columnValuePrepare); 
     foreach ($columnValues as $columnValueDatasets) {
        foreach ($columnValueDatasets as  &$columnValue) {
            if (is_numeric($columnValue)) {
                $databaseFetch->bindParam($i, $columnValue, PDO::PARAM_INT);    
            } else {
                $databaseFetch->bindParam($i, $columnValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
            $i++;           
        }
    }
    $databaseFetch->execute();
}

function testQuery($tableName, $columnNames,$columnValuesArr) {
    $i = 0;
    $placeholders = '';
    $columnValuesForTest = '(';
    $columnValuePrepare = '('; 
    $columnValues = $columnValuesArr;
    $columnNamesArr = explode(',', $columnNames);
    $columnCount = count($columnNamesArr);
    end($columnValuesArr);
    //fetch key of the last element of the array.
    $lastElementKey = key($columnValuesArr);
    foreach ($columnValuesArr as $columnKey => $columnValueDatasets) {
        foreach ($columnValueDatasets as  &$columnValue) {
            $placeholders .= '?,';
            $columnValuesForTest .= $columnValue .  ',' ;
            $i++;
        }
        $placeholders = rtrim($placeholders, ',');
        $columnValuePrepare = rtrim($columnValuePrepare, ',');
        $columnValuesForTest = rtrim($columnValuesForTest, ',');
        if ($columnKey == $lastElementKey) {
            $columnValuePrepare .= $placeholders . ')';
            $columnValuesForTest .= $columnValue . ')';
        } else {
            $columnValuePrepare .= $placeholders . '),(';
            $columnValuesForTest .= $columnValue . '),(';
        }
        $i = 0;
        $placeholders = '';
    } 
    echo 'SQL Query which would be placed into Prepared Statement: <br/> INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . $columnNames . ')
    VALUES ' . $columnValuePrepare;
    echo '<br/><br/>';
echo 'SQL Query with Values how it would look if you make it without Prepared Statement (Surely we do it with prepared Statement we dont bring you into Trouble: <br/> INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . $columnNames . ')
    VALUES ' . $columnValuesForTest;
    echo '<br/><br/>Now lets see that more readable:<br/>';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($columnValues as $columnValueDatasets) {
        foreach ($columnValueDatasets as  &$columnValue) {
            if (is_numeric($columnValue)) {
                echo ($columnValue) . ',';
            } else {
                echo '"' . $columnValue . '",';
            }
            $i++;           
        }
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is *so* entangled that I am having a really hard time deciphering it. I think you should take a step back and make a simplified version. Start from ditching named placeholders, they add a LOT of mess. I even have no idea why you're using them for automated placeholders that noone is going to see

Comment: Ya in this case it maybe was a bad idea. It was simply my normal way to build a Query with a prepared statement. But with normal queries it spare work because you don't need to use a ton of bindParam lines.  I tried it out and it seems to go through